# Buttons still functioning even when if statement isn't met?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to programming. About 3 weeks in. I am needing to create a dice game.

```
/*
GAME RULES:

- The game has 2 players, playing in rounds
- In each turn, a player rolls a dice as many times as he whishes. Each result get added to his ROUND score
- BUT, if the player rolls a 1, all his ROUND score gets lost. After that, it's the next player's turn
- The player can choose to 'Hold', which means that his ROUND score gets added to his GLBAL score. After that, it's the next player's turn
- The first player to reach 100 points on GLOBAL score wins the game

*/

// Scoring 
let scores, roundScore, activePlayer, gamePlaying;
let diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');




function init() {
    scores = [0, 0];
    roundScore = 0;
    activePlayer = 0;
    gamePlaying = true;
    document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('winner')
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('winner')
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('active')
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('name-0').textContent = 'Player 1'
    document.getElementById('name-1').textContent = 'Player 2'

}

init();

if (gamePlaying) {
    // Next Player
    function nextPlayer() {

        activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
        roundScore = 0;
        document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0'
        document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0'

        document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active')
        document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active')

    }


    document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // 1. Dice Roll
        let dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

        // Display the Result
        diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
        diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';


        // Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1
        if (dice !== 1) {
            // Add Score
            roundScore += dice
            document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
        } else {
            // Next Player 
            nextPlayer()
        }

    });

    // Hold button
    document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function () {
        // add current score to global score
        // scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;
        scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;
        document.querySelector('#score-' + activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];
        if ((scores[activePlayer]) >= 10) {
            document.getElementById('name-' + activePlayer).textContent = 'Winner!'
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.add('winner')
            document.querySelector('.player-' + activePlayer + '-panel').classList.remove('active')
            diceDOM.style.display = 'none';
            gamePlaying = false;



        } else {
            nextPlayer();
        }
    });

}
// New Game 
document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click', init);
```

When 10 points is reached, gamePlaying is set to false. I have wrapped everything except the new game button inside an if statement for when gamePlaying is true.

However, the other buttons still work when gamePlaying is set to false. As far as I understand, they shouldn't work at all since they are inside the if statement saying that gamePlaying must be set to true.

Here is the project:

https://filebin.net/e898mu9p5t7ivzeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition `if (gamePlaying) {` is in the global scope. That means it will execute only once right after page load. Since gamePlaying is `true` at that time, your event handlers are registered. Event handlers regardless of `gamePlaying` value because there is no condition inside the event handlers.

**Solution:**
Remove the global if condition and add the condition inside each button click handlers in appropriate places.

Comment: Your solution worked! The init() function should run on page load and set gamePlaying to true though, shouldn't it?

Still trying to get my head around scope and when things execute.
Thank you very much for the explanation, definitely sets me on the right path :)

Comment: Glad I was able to helped. Just corrected my answer based on your comment.